# C binary file handling

Tags: c, pointers, binaryfiles

I'm not used to programm (Since i'm a newcomer) so I'd like to get some help with this project... I'm trying to make a maker/reader programm using binary files, structs and pointers but my programm crashes every time this and his process

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Recipe{
    char name[30];
    char difficulty[30];
    double calories; 
};

void generate_file(FILE *in){
    fopen("recipe.bin", "wb");
    if(in == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "\nErro, o arquivo não pode ser aberto\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    struct Recipe *recipe = malloc(sizeof(struct Recipe));
    printf("Digite o nome da receita: ");
    gets(recipe->name);
    printf("Digite o nivel de dificuldade da receita: ");
    gets(recipe->difficulty);
    printf("Digite o número de calorias: ");
    scanf("%d", &recipe->calories);
    
    fwrite(&recipe, sizeof(struct Recipe), 1, in);
    
    if(fwrite != 0){
        printf("Arquivo salvo com sucesso!");
    }else{
        printf("Falha no salvamento de dados");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    fclose(in);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    
    FILE *in;
    generate_file(in);
}
```

Comment: You don't want this line: `if(fwrite != 0){`, instead test the return of the previous call to `fwrite`. Also don' t use `gets` It is no longer part of the language, instead use `fgets`

Comment: `fopen` returns a `FILE *`. I think you need to change the `FILE *in` parameter into a variable, especially as the `in` parameter value passed in from `main` is uninitialized.

Comment: Using name `in` for a file that is meant for output is a bit strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program crashes because you pass uninitialized or wrong pointers to certain functions.

From top to bottom:

Change the declaration of *generate_file* so that it takes a filename and returns an integer, like this:

```
int generate_file(const char *filename)
```

Assign the result from *fopen* to *in*, like this:

```
FILE *in = fopen(filename, "wb");
```

Replace exit with return:

```
return 1;
```

Initialize the structure after creation with zeros, for easier troubleshooting:

```
memset(recipe, 0, sizeof(struct Recipe));
```

Replace %d when scanning calories with %lf:

```
scanf("%lf", &recipe->calories);
```

Do not dereference the recipe (replace **&recipe** with **recipe**) when calling fwrite - it already is a pointer. Assign result of fwrite function into a variable and then test the variable instead of the function pointer when checking how many items were written:

```
size_t written = fwrite(recipe, sizeof(struct Recipe), 1, in);
if (written != 0) {
```

Again, replace *exit* with *return* and use a different value then before, so that you can distinguish the cause of the problem later:

```
return 2;
```

Free the memory allocated for recipe:

```
free(recipe);
```

In *main()*, change the argument to the name of the file and use the result from called function:

```
int result = generate_file("recipe.bin");
return result;
```

Here is the complete code:

```
int generate_file(const char *filename) {
    FILE* in = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if(in == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nErro, o arquivo não pode ser aberto\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    struct Recipe *recipe = malloc(sizeof(struct Recipe));
    memset(recipe, 0, sizeof(struct Recipe));
    printf("Digite o nome da receita: ");
    gets(recipe->name);
    printf("Digite o nivel de dificuldade da receita: ");
    gets(recipe->difficulty);
    printf("Digite o número de calorias: ");
    scanf("%lf", &recipe->calories);
    
    size_t written = fwrite(recipe, sizeof(struct Recipe), 1, in);
    
    if(written != 0){
        printf("Arquivo salvo com sucesso!");
    }else{
        printf("Falha no salvamento de dados");
        return 2;
    }
    
    free(recipe);
    fclose(in);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int result = generate_file("recipe.bin");
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use `in` as your file? You don't assign the return value of `fopen` to `in`. `in` points to nothing, so using I/O functions such as `fwrite` on it will cause some errors.

```c
in = fopen("recipe.bin", "wb");
```

Also, `fwrite` expects a pointer, not a pointer to a pointer, since `recipe` is already a pointer, you don't need to `&`. `fwrite(const void *ptr..)`

**Side note: You should never use `gets`, it is not a safe function as it might cause an overflow. Use `fgets` instead.**